# Node openid-connect + Gmail/FB auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I working on Nodejs with express framework for rest api.

Also i am using **openid-connect**  for login purpose. this module will return access_token finally(insert data into table access_token,refresh_token), That token I will share to front-end and mobile app or whatever. Now I am trying to implement Gmail/FB, I understand they will give token for respective Gamil.FB. 
In my case I need how to insert the tokens and other stuff.

```
var oidc_opt = {
    login_url : '/auth/login',
    consent_url : '/auth/consent',
    scopes : {
        user : 'Access to User Information',
        fetchit : 'Access to XXX Information'
    },
    app : app
};
var oidc = require('openid-connect').oidc(oidc_opt);
```

Anyone give some ideas to approch.